# Aligning images and text vertically inside div

Tags: html, css, positioning, vertical-alignment

Is the only way of aligning images and text vertically within a div possible via absolute/relative positioning?

I need to do that, and I am trying to use as few classes/hacks as possible.

Is the only other way to do like display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;?

Example code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/UYxXG/

Comment: previous works, but i think i like solution i came up with-->  http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/7SV9f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted above in comment, but this code works for anyone else who is interested --->

http://jsfiddle.net/ndreckshage/7SV9f/

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use **display: table-cell**  with **vertical-align: middle**.

See an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/UYxXG/3/

One problem with this method is, is that the property "table-cell"  is not supported by IE7.

Comment: ya i saw that approach on google/so when searching for solution, but my main problem with it (dont care about ie7) is that the elements are grouped as one, so if it is icon text icon, they would appear jagged like they do in your jsfiddle.

Comment: so to rephrase - i want each individual image/text to be centered within the container div, so the images/text look good together. i know this can be done with relative/absolute positioning easily, it is just annoying to have to create so many extra css hacks when this should be dealt with in an easier way (in my opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Vertical align is one way, absolute/relative positioning is another, but there is also the html align attribute. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_align

In my opinion adding to your css with vertical-align is the smartest way.

```
.test
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier has a great article on CSS Tricks that shows how to center single and multiline text vertically with css. http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/